# Is there an other solution calculate data by filtered date without "with" clause?

Tags: time, google-bigquery

Need to calculate value when date< first_date by name with interval 3 day in BigQuery.
Example of data:

```
+------+------------+------------------+
| Name |    date    | order_id | value |
+------+------------+----------+-------+
| JONES| 2019-01-03 | 11       |    10 |
| JONES| 2019-01-05 | 12       |    5  |
| JONES| 2019-06-03 | 13       |    3  |
| JONES| 2019-07-03 | 14       |    20 |
| John | 2019-07-23 | 15       |    10 |
+------+------------+----------+-------+
```

My solution is:

```
 WITH data AS (
      SELECT "JONES" name, DATE("2019-01-03") date_time, 11 order_id, 10 value
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-01-05"), 12, 5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-06-03"), 13, 3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-07-03"), 14, 20
      UNION ALL
      SELECT "John", DATE("2019-07-23"), 15, 10
    ),
data2 AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY name) min_date
    FROM data
)    
    SELECT name,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(order_id as f_id, date_time as f_date) ORDER BY order_id LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*,
    sum(case when date_time< date_add(min_date,interval 3 day) then value  end)  as total_value_day3,
    SUM(value) AS total
    FROM data2
    GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------------+----------------+------+
| name | f_id | f_date     |total_value_day3| total|
+------+------+------------+----------------+------+
| JONES| 11   | 2019-01-03 | 15             | 38   | 
| John | 15   | 2019-07-23 | 10             | 10   | 
+------+------+------------+----------------+------+
```

So my question, can do the same calculated with a more effective way?
Or this solution is ok for large datasets?

Comment: i would suggest looking into [Query plan and timeline](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation)  to find out what your query does on your currect dataset..  it's to hard to predict how this query will scale on the "larger big data" sets as we don't know the table structures and or defined indexes..

Comment: This solution is effective enough I think. If the data is not heavily skewed, which is, there are names with millions of rows in the window, it should work well on a pretty large dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gets the same results without using window functions or array aggregations, so BQ has to do less ordering/partitioning.  For this small example, my query takes longer to run, but there is less byte shuffling.  If you run this against a much larger dataset, I think mine will be more efficient.

```
 WITH data AS (
      SELECT "JONES" name, DATE("2019-01-03") date_time, "11" order_id, 10 value       UNION ALL
      SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-01-05"), "12", 5      UNION ALL
      SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-06-03"), "13", 3      UNION ALL
      SELECT "JONES", DATE("2019-07-03"), "14", 20     UNION ALL
      SELECT "John", DATE("2019-07-23"), "15", 10    
),
aggs as (
    select name, min(date_time) as first_order_date, min(order_id) as first_order_id, sum(value) as total
    from data
    group by 1
)    
select 
  name,
  first_order_id as f_id,
  first_order_date as f_date, 
  sum(value) as total_value_day3,
  total
from aggs
inner join data using(name)
where date_time < date_add(first_order_date, interval 3 day) -- <= perhaps
group by 1,2,3,5
```

Note, this makes an assumption that order_id is sequential (aka order_id 11 always occurs before order_id 12) in the same manner that dates are sequential.

Comment: quiz: order_id is STRING data type here - so do you think "110" will go after "12"?!

Comment: answer: hoping his stringified order_id in the CTE is a mistake, and his actual table has it stored as an Int

Comment: i really doubt that this is a case as in real life in most cases such field is not just simple integer :o) but who knows  - especially that OP accepted the answer :o)

Comment: yes, it was mistakes by my side about type for order__id